# For loop not breaking after conditional statement is met

Tags: php

I'm trying to increment decimal places on php but it doesn't break inside the if statement

```
for($x = 0; $x <= 1; $x += 0.001){
    //0.01 = 0.010
    if($x===0.01){
        break;  
    }
    echo $x.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @corashina yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact in PHP (or really any language).  Read [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for a general explanation of why this is the case.
As a result, the loop counter might not ever have the *exact* value `0.01`.  Instead, you could break when the dummy variable has exceeded a threshold of `0.01`:

```
for ($x=0; $x <= 1; $x += 0.001) {
    // 0.01 = 0.010
    if ($x >= 0.01) {
        break;
    }

    echo $x . '<br>';
}
```

When tested locally, the above script is printing:

```
0<br>0.001<br>0.002<br>0.003<br>0.004<br>0.005<br>0.006<br>0.007<br>0.008<br>0.009<br>
```